# How is the first element of this empty list 0?

Tags: j

Consider:

```
   {. ''          NB. makes sense...

   </. ''         NB. still makes sense....

   {. </. ''      NB. umm... where did that zero come from?
0
   '' -: </. ''   NB. and why is it behaving differently from line 1?
1                 NB. which is apparently identical to?
```

What explains these seeming contradictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### where did that zero came from?

Per [NuVoc page](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlylfdot) for `{.` (Head):

> If `y` has no items, `{. y` produces an item of fill atoms.

```
   {.0$0
0
```

#### why is it behaving differently

`-:` returns boolean `1` only if shape and content of its arguments are the same. `</.''` is an empty list with no elements and shape `0` (so as `''`), whereas `{.''` is an atom: `$` (Shape of it) gives an empty list:

```
   ${.''

   $${.''
0
```

And `u:` says that it's a space sharacter (ASCII 32):

```
   3 u:{.''
32
```